# Remove old marker add new one after call ajax method every x second with OpenLayers

Tags: javascript, ajax, openlayers, openstreetmap

I want to change marker position for every x seconds using ajax method but i am facing 1 issue for that is the new marker is adding on OpenLayers but old marker is not removing from OpenLayers. I want to remove old marker first and then add new marker in updated place.

```
  function ShowCurrentTime() {
      var obj = {};
      obj.device_id = $.trim($("\[id*=txtdevice_id\]").val());
      var marker;
      var mapOptions;
      $.ajax({
          url: "TRACKING.aspx/GetData",
          data: JSON.stringify(obj),
          type: "POST",
          dataType: "json",
          contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
          success: function(data) {
              if (data.d != '') {
                  var lat = data.d\[1\];
                  var lng = data.d\[2\];
              }
              $.each(data, function(index, value) {
                  var zoom = 13;
                  var marker = new OpenLayers.Layer.Markers("Markers");
                  var lonLat = new OpenLayers.LonLat(lng, lat).transform(new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"), map.getProjectionObject());
                  map.addLayer(marker);
                  map.removeLayer(marker);
                  marker.addMarker(new OpenLayers.Marker(lonLat));
                  map.setCenter(lonLat, zoom);
              });
          }
      });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

you are initializing the marker again in ajax, remove first and then initialize it again

this should work

```
function ShowCurrentTime() {
      var obj = {};
      obj.device_id = $.trim($("\[id*=txtdevice_id\]").val());
      var marker = null;
      var mapOptions;
      $.ajax({
          url: "TRACKING.aspx/GetData",
          data: JSON.stringify(obj),
          type: "POST",
          dataType: "json",
          contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
          success: function(data) {
              if (data.d != '') {
                  var lat = data.d\[1\];
                  var lng = data.d\[2\];
              }
              $.each(data, function(index, value) {
                  var zoom = 13;
                  if (marker != null) map.removeLayer(marker);
                  marker = new OpenLayers.Layer.Markers("Markers");
                  var lonLat = new OpenLayers.LonLat(lng, lat).transform(new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"), map.getProjectionObject());
                  map.addLayer(marker);
                  marker.addMarker(new OpenLayers.Marker(lonLat));
                  map.setCenter(lonLat, zoom);
              });
          }
      });
  }
```

Comment: I put this code in my application. but its not removing old marker, old and new both marker still show, i want to remove old and add new one on updated place.